# Get user in Session_OnEnd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple question - how do I get the currently authenticated user in Session_OnEnd() in Global.asax?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
    public void Session_OnEnd()
    {
        string user = User.Identity.Name;
    }
```

But I get the exception "User is not available in this context.".
How would I get the current user otherwise?
Should I store the name in a session variable when they log in? Is this not redundant?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I thought this question was very specific to asp MVC so I put it in the title. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It can be specific as it wants - but that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sessions (mostly) end on the server after a time of inactivity. As such, there is no Request and so no User identity available at this point (as there is no authentication token to identify a user).

So you're right, if you need to know the user's name at the time the session ends, it will need to be a value in `Session`. It may seem a little redundant, but it's going to be your only option if this is what you need.